# React/Redux - Allow custom params when defining selectors

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a Redux store in my React app and I'm following the pattern of using selectors to search for certain keys within Redux store. I know you can pass `state` and `props` as arguments inside a selector, but can you also pass extra arguments? I'd like to have one selector where you can supply an argument to find a key inside the store (in this case `cookie`), rather than write separate selectors for each key. Can `testQuantity` be used as a function to grab the key I need?

Component (some code removed for brevity)

```
componentWillMount() {
    const a = testQuantity;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    testQuantity: selectTestQuantity(state, props),
});
```

Store

```
"store": {
    "homepage": {
        "cookie_1": 1,
        "cookie_2": 2,
    }
}
```

Selector

```
export const selectCookie = state => state.getIn(['store', 'homepage', 'cookie_1']);

export const selectCookie = state => state.getIn(['store', 'homepage', 'cookie_2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to update my function within mapStateToProps:

```
testQuantity: cookieName => selectTestQuantity(state, cookieName)
```

Comment: be careful with this, as you may be breaking memoization.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances

Comment: @thejohnbackes i was reading about the issue with memoization with selectors. But isn't this only a concern if I have multiple instances of a component using the same selector? In this case, I will only use the selector from one instance of the component.